# Cypress with Auth0.com login and redirects

Tags: cypress, auth0

We have changed our login page so it's now redirecting to auth0.com and then back to our domain after you login to auth0. The issue is now when I login I get redirected to our QA environment which requires authentication so once the test submits the form I get a 401.

Before auth0 I was getting around the 401 by overwritting the visit function passing in a auth header.

If I try to visit our QA environment first before going to our login page I get

```
You may only cy.visit() same-origin URLs within a single test.
```

I've seen other questions asked about auth0 but not with also requiring authentication in the redirect, is it possible to still run tests on our QA environment?

Answer (score 0):

While the Cypress team works to resolve [max 1 site... support visiting multiple superdomains in one test](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/944#issuecomment-853129902) on work around I have used in the past is [this](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/944#issuecomment-788373384): detailed again below.

In `commands.js`

```
// -- Save localStorage between tests
let LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY = {};

Cypress.Commands.add('saveLocalStorage', () => {
  Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(key => {
    LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY[key] = localStorage[key];
  });
});

Cypress.Commands.add('restoreLocalStorage', () => {
  Object.keys(LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY).forEach(key => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, LOCAL_STORAGE_MEMORY[key]);
  });
});

// -- Visit multiple domains in one test
Cypress.Commands.add('forceVisit', url => {
  cy.window().then(win => {
    return win.open(url, '_self');
  });
});
```

In `test.spec.js`

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

context('Force Visit', () => {
  it('should be able to visit and assert on two domains', () => {
    cy.forceVisit('https://example.cypress.io');
    cy.title().should('eq', 'Cypress.io: Kitchen Sink');
    cy.forceVisit('https://www.google.com');
    cy.title().should('eq', 'Google');
  });
});

context('Auth Flow', () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.forceVisit('<auth url>');
    cy.get('<username input>').type('<username>');
    cy.get('<password input>').type('<password>');
    cy.intercept('POST', '<auth login request>').as('auth');
    cy.get('<submit button>').click();
    cy.wait('@auth');
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    cy.saveLocalStorage();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.restoreLocalStorage();
    // Preserve Cookies between tests
    Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
      preserve: /[\s\S]*/,
    });
  });

  it('should be able to start in authorized state', () => {
    cy.visit('<site url>');
  });
});
```